# Getting build error while building docker image for asp.net app

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-web-api2, containers, dockerfile

I created a simple ASP.NET Web API (4.5.2 framework) application.

This is a simple project I created using file > New > Project > Web > Asp.net web application and selecting ASP.NET Web Api option.

I am trying to create a Docker image getting following error.

Here is my script

```
#escape=`

# get the build agent image to build the project
FROM sixeyed/msbuild:netfx-4.5.2-webdeploy As build-agent

WORKDIR C:\Users\jason\source\repos\FirstApp\FirstApp
COPY FirstApp\packages.config .
RUN nuget restore packages.config -PackagesDirectory ..\packages

COPY FirstApp\ C:\Users\jason\source\repos\FirstApp\FirstApp
RUN msbuild FirstApp.csproj /p:OutputPath=c:\out /p:DeployOnBuild=true `
 /p:VSToolsPath=C:\MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStuio.Web.targets.14.0.0.3\tools\VSToolsPath

#docker image build --tag firstapp --file .\Dockerfile .

# now build the app
FROM microsoft/aspnet:windowsservercore
SHELL ["powershell"]

WORKDIR c:\web-app
RUN Remove-Website -Name  'Default Web Site'; `
    New-Website -Name 'web-app' -Port 80 -PhysicalPath 'C:\web-app'

copy --from=build-agent c:\out\_PublishedWebsites\FirstApp c:\web-app
```

I am getting following error:

```
Step 10/11 : RUN Remove-Website -Name  'Default Web Site';  New-Website -Name 'web-app' -Port 80 -PhysicalPath 'C:\web-app'
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e37d8f12a4f7
Step 11/11 : copy --from=build-agent c:\out\_PublishedWebsites\FirstApp c:\web-app
docker : COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\Volume{ffe73e3d-cc0b-11e8-a943-00155d1c3a78}\out\_PublishedWebsites\FirstApp: The system cannot find the path specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ docker image build --tag firstapp --file .\Dockerfile .
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (COPY failed: Cr...path specified.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

**I looked and found, there is no c:\out folder. I do not see this folder after executing this command as well:**

```
RUN msbuild FirstApp.csproj /p:OutputPath=c:\out /p:DeployOnBuild=true `
 /p:VSToolsPath=C:\MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStuio.Web.targets.14.0.0.3\tools\VSToolsPath
```

[image]

Seems like a simple issue but I am not sure where can I see logs and how to fix this issue.